# Deriving a full conditional distribution when Half-t distribution is used

Tags: bayesian, t-distribution, gibbs

I'm trying to use a Half-t distribution with Gibbs sampling to form a model. but having hard time finding the full conditional distribution.
Suppose $$Y = X \beta + \epsilon $$, where $Y$ is a Gaussian process and $\epsilon$ is a Gauss-distributed noise with mean 0 and variance $\sigma_\epsilon^2 I_n$ ($I_n$ is an n by n identity matrix).
If the prior distribution of $\sigma_\epsilon^2$ is a Half-t distribution with fixed $\nu$ and $\sigma$, what would be the full conditional distribution for $\sigma_\epsilon^2$?
Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, I misremembered this one -- it comes out to a folded noncentral t.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you for the comment. Is there a paper or a book that shows the full derivation?